# How to change glyphicon icon class on click event?

Tags: javascript, angular5

I have list of submenu at the sidebar with an glyphicon icon. My one li is clicked the icon should be changed. At the moment when I click on one li all the icon are being changed.

This is the code I am working on. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

### HTML

```
<ul class="nav third-nav">
    <li appExpandMenu (click)="changeIcon()">
        <a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-{{sign}} arrow"></span>
            <span class="third-menu-title">Sales</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav third-nav">
    <li appExpandMenu (click)="changeIcon()">
        <a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-{{sign}} arrow"></span>
            <span class="third-menu-title">Report</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

### ts.

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {   
    sign = 'up';

    changeIcon(): void {
        if (this.sign == 'up') {
            this.sign = 'right';
        } else {
            this.sign = 'up';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `ngClass`? `<span [ngClass]="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-{{sign}} arrow"></span>`

Comment: @veben i have not tried ngClass.. how to use it here

Answer (score 1):

here is a working 
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryjnol)
of what you need, if you have any question regarding the code don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: your code is ok but my glyphicon is at right side and when I click your code make it appear at left side.

Comment: i think you should add a "arrow" class to the class name in the ts file:el.nativeElement.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up arrow";

Comment: I have a question why there is if and else if with same code

Comment: i don't fully understand your question, but i think you are asking why i used if and else if instead of if else, coz i assumed that you have more than two menu, but if you have just two you can edit to be if else.

Comment: if (el.nativeElement.id== numb) {
            this.ToggleIconClass(el);
          }
          else if ((el.nativeElement.id== numb) ){
          this.ToggleIconClass(el);}
        } Are they same condition ?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry for the bug you can delete  the else  statement